# Everchanging Url Parameter in MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, httprequest

I'm looking at Jquery BootGrid and came across an odd problem. BootGrid posts a parameter in an ajax Post, that changes in identity on any given request.

Given that a sort parameter in a post to my MVC5 Action can be different each time a post is made, like this :-

```
 sort[forename]='asc' 
 sort[forename]='desc' 
 sort[surname]='asc'
 sort[surname]='desc'
 sort[dateofbirth]='asc'
 sort[dateofbirth]='desc'
```

What is the most elegant way of catching this with my Action method.I struggle to see how deal with this, I need to work out which property it is that i need to order by and in what direction, but extracting that out of the example above seems difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, what do you want to know and what do you want the output to be? Is it whether it is forename, surname or dob or whether it is asc or desc?

Comment: Hey, I need to know if its forename, surname or dateofbirth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

catch sort parameter on your server function as:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sort
```

value example:

```
sort[Description] = asc //(key = Description, value = asc)
```

The key is the field to sort for and the value the direction.
Check always if is just one element on the dictionary, because if no field was selected the parameter has 2 elements:

```
sort[controller]= controller name, sort[action] = action name
```

it works for me. See an example of all the parameter you should pass to your function

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult yourfunction(int current, int rowCount, string searchPhrase, Dictionary<string, string> sort)
```

Javascript code

```
var grid = $("#grid").bootgrid({
    /* static URL */
    ajax: "true",
    url: "/controller/yourfunction"});
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question above?

Comment: Derek is asking how to catch the sort parameter of Jquery BootGrid on the server side function. The documentation doesn't say anything about it (check here [link](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation)). and the parameter seems like its always changing. I had the same problem and that's how you catch it, is a dictionary not an string.

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry if it wasn't clear before, I assume he will understand since he was working on the same problem I had.

Comment: That's a much better answer

Answer (score 1):

You can search like this http://jsfiddle.net/a14v0cqc/7/:

```
var lookFor = [ "forename", "surname", "dateofbirth" ];
var sort = [];

sort['dateofbirth']='desc'

 function whichIsPopulated(){
     var value = "";
     $(lookFor).each(function(i, key){
         if(typeof sort[key] !== 'undefined'){
             value = key;
             return;    
         }
     });

     return value;
 };

 function valuePopulated(){
     return sort[whichIsPopulated()];
 };

alert(whichIsPopulated());
alert(valuePopulated());
```

If you add another value to the lookFor array it will also check for that.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but its when i recieve the post at server side that is the problem, the javascipt that generate the ajax post is done by Jquery BootGrid

Comment: What language are you using server side?

Comment: C#? Mac is a framework and can you post up the action so we can see the data type or the parameter and so on